# How to display the SaveAs dialog?

Tags: vba, ms-word

`ActiveDocument.SaveAs`, from what I can read is supposed to display the SaveAs dialog. In my case it saves the file without further ado, no user interaction.

I want try to set the filename prior to the user being prompted as in: `ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=sFilenamevar`  (like report-20231018-105131.docx)

This is the dialog box. I need to give the user the ability to change the calculated name:
[image: Copy of the Safe this file dialog]

If someone could confirm that it could not be done that would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveDocument.SaveAs` (and its updated cousin `ActiveDocument.SaveAs2`) just save the document, they don't show the dialog ... see the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2).

You can try

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = sFilenamevar
    If .Show Then
        MsgBox "You saved the Document as '" & ActiveDocument.Name & "'"
    Else
        MsgBox "You didn't save the Document"
    End If
End With
```

Which shows the older-style 'save as' dialog.